# Create silent installation using Installshield Limited Edition

Tags: installshield-le

I want to create a Silent installation for MS SqlExpress; how can i create a Silent Installation just by one window and install SQLExpress 2008 using **InstallShield**?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Application to run tab and add this line to parameters to run

```
/quiet /qn
```